# Orchard CMS: How to preview svg image in MediaLibrary?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Is the way to preview svg image in Media Library? 
Is there way to extend Orchard 1.8.2 for that?

[image: Orchard media library with svg]

Comment: Poop-icon? Pee-icon? Aren't you just relieved you can't preview these SVGs?